# How to set up run bash file when starting run docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to run a bash file every time when I start to run the docker image, but couldn't figure how to do this with a few hours already. my bash file looks like,

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;
do
   echo "hello world"
   sleep 10
done
```

So what I am thinking about is, when I start running the docker, the bash file will also be running inside the docker image continuously, in this case, the bash file will do its job as long as the docker is on.

How to set this up? should I build this inside the docker image? or I can put bash file in run.sh so it happens when docker runs?

Comment: What have you tried so far?   Have you read through the docs on [creating images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockerimages/)? Which parts are unclear?

Comment: Hi. @Iarsks, I have tried to add the file path into Dockerfile.in and build the docker image, which works great, thank you. But is there a method to do this without rebuilding the docker image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy your script file with COPY or ADD in the docker file and then use the CMD command to run it..

For example, if u copy run.sh to /
Then in you dockerfile last line just add:

```
CMD run.sh
```

for more info please refer to: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/ and search for 'CMD'

make sure that the file has the right privileges for running (otherwise, after COPY/ADD the file make `RUN chmod +x run.sh`

Summary:

```
//Dockerfile

// source image, for example node.js 
FROM some_image

// copy run.sh script from your local file system into the image (to root dir)
ADD run.sh /

// add execute privillages to the script file (just in case it doesn't have)
RUN chmod +x run.sh

// default behaviour when containter will start
CMD run.sh
```

hope that's help.

Comment: Hi, ItayB, so I need add into the Docker File and then re-build the docker, right?

Comment: @HaipengSu correct. I'll add a comment before each line to help you understand what is going on.. if it solve your problem please accept this answer :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, that is awesome. Is there a method to do this without rebuild the docker image?  like insert the file path variable into run.sh?

Comment: Yes. you can 'map' a specific folder (where the script is located in your file system) - into the container file system with a specific path.. but it a different question.. You can add new question and try to answer it properly..

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Let me try.

Comment: @HaipengSu Just to help you find it.. look for the 'docker run -v /some/src/path:/some/dst/path'

Answer (score 1):

Your Dockerfile needs look looke this

```
FROM <base_image>
ADD yourfile.sh /
CMD ['/yourfile.sh']
```